# Should I add Postleaf's cache folder to gitignore

Tags: content-management-system, gitignore

Trying out Postleaf, and just wondering what I should add to my .gitignore file for my web project.  I see there is a cache folder there, and I'm guessing this is a candidate for my .gitignore, but I didn't find documentation specific to this.  And are there other candidates that I should look at ignoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specific documentation, you can take a clue from the GitHub [Postleaf/postleaf](https://github.com/Postleaf/postlea) project itself.

[Its `.gitignore`](https://github.com/Postleaf/postleaf/blob/ffa22b3530b553dddb63bef0bd75d667493d7001/.gitignore) does include the cache:

```
# Files
.DS_Store
.env

# Directories
.vscode/
cache/
data/
design/
node_modules/
themes/
uploads/
```